# Upload Zip Chunks and Join them on Azure Platform

Tags: azure, storage, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

I want to know that.. If I make chunks of a big Zip file and upload all chunks on Azure Cloud Storage in Container Blobs. Can i Join these chunks on Azure Platform.?
for chunking i am using this code which is also generating .bat file for rejoining the chunks..

```cs
public void SplitFile(){
    int numericUpDown = 100;//in MB
    string PathToCopyChunks = "";  // path to store chunks and ( .bat  ) file
    string FilePathMakeChunks = DirectoryNameToPutScannedData; //the path of file to make chunks.
    try{
        int kbs = numericUpDown * 1024;
        int chunkSize = numericUpDown * 1024 * 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        string cmdout = "copy/b ";
        FileStream infile = File.OpenRead(FilePathMakeChunks);
        for (long i = 0; i <= infile.Length / chunkSize; i++)
        {
            string fname = Path.Combine(PathToCopyChunks, Path.Combine(PathToCopyChunks, Path.GetFileName(FilePathMakeChunks)) + "." + chunkSize + "." + i.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0') + ".part");
            string fname_x = Path.GetFileName(FilePathMakeChunks) + "." + chunkSize + "." + i.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0') + ".part";
            if (i == infile.Length / chunkSize)
                cmdout += "\"" + fname_x + "\"";
            else
                cmdout += "\"" + fname_x + "\" + ";
            FileStream outfile = File.Create(fname);
            for (int kb = 0; kb <= kbs; kb++)
            {
                int len = infile.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
                outfile.Write(buffer, 0, len); 
            }
            outfile.Close();
        }
        cmdout += " \"" + Path.GetFileName(FilePathMakeChunks) + "\"";
        string combinerbatch = Path.Combine(PathToCopyChunks, Path.Combine(PathToCopyChunks, Path.GetFileName(DirectoryNameToPutScannedData)) + "." + chunkSize + ".combine.bat");
        File.WriteAllText(combinerbatch, cmdout);
        MessageBox.Show("Splitting Done...!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

I am uploading these chunks along with batch file in azure storage container and i want to run this batch file at my azure container to join chunks.
hope this will help to understand my Question

And I am using this code for Uploading

```cs
string[] array1 = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Test");
string fileName = string.Empty;
foreach (string name in array1)
{
    fileName = Path.GetFileName(name);
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
    var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(name);
    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream); 
}
```

Comment: Could you describe more the  reason you need to separate the chunks, upload to different blobs, download, and then rejoin? Is this a perf issue or some other application-specific reason?

Comment: @Emily Because my file is about 10 GB that's why i am making chunks. In chunks uploading is easy with low internet speed. or if i need parallel uploading in future then it will be help full.

Comment: If you use the client library UploadFromStream method (as I see you are) this will chunk it for you and upload in parallel if you set your parallelism factor to >1. Is there a reason this isn't working for you?

Comment: @Emily as i told my file is about 10 GB and on my internet speed it takes about 3 hr to upload a file with 1 GB.and if somehow i disconnect with my internet connection then it will start from start to upload a file....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're two things:

1. If you're looking to zip the files in blob storage i.e. upload large files in blob storage and are expecting blob storage to zip those files there, then it is not possible. Blob storage is simple file storage.
2. If you have a large zip file that you want to upload in chunks and then have blob storage reassemble these chunks to create the zip file, then it is possible.

Since you didn't mention the technology you want to use, I will use [`Azure REST API`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135733.aspx) to describe the process.

What you would need to do is split the file on the client side (from where you are uploading) in chunks. Each chunk can't be more than 4MB in size and because a block blob's maximum size can be 200GB, you can't have more than 50,000 chunks. Then you will upload these chunks using [`Put Block`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135726.aspx) API.

Once all blocks are uploaded, you will instruct Blob storage to create the zip file using [`Put Block List`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179467.aspx) API.

Comment: Gaurav, i have 10 gb zip file and i am making chunks with my code which is also creating batch (.bat) file to rejoin these chunks. i am uploading these chunks and batch file on azure cloud storage using simple uploading code. now i want to run that batch file to rejoin the chunks in azure container where my chunks are also uploaded . is it possible??

Comment: Please include your code in your question so that we know what you're doing in the batch file. But it is possible. Take a look at `Put Block List` operation.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code there instead of putting your code in comments.

Comment: I could imagine solutions using Azure Data Factory that can orchestrate your batch command for joining. 

Otherwise, you might need to mount the blobstorage on a Azure VM and run the bat on that.

Comment: If this is just a perf issue and you're using the storage client libs you can try using any of the upload* methods with the parallelism factor of your choosing and this will chunk the file and then upload to a single blob in parallel. No work on your part then.